# Spanning a cell across several rows in TikZ-matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Using the `matrix`-library of TikZ I am producing the following image:
[image: current layout]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,font=\small,
    every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,rectangle, minimum height=2.5em, text centered},
    comp/.style={draw,very thick,text width=2.5cm,fill=blue!10},
    crit/.style={draw,text width=2cm}]
\matrix [ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=1.5mm, row sep=3mm]
{
\node [comp] {Category\\One}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\One}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Two}; \&
\\
\node [comp] {Category\\Two}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Three}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Four};
\\
\node [comp] {Category\\Three}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Five}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Six}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Seven};
\\
\node [comp] {Category\\Four}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Eight}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Nine}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Ten}; \&
\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now, I'd like to extend this slightly to achieve such a layout (don't mind the different colours):
[image: target layout]

I just can't figure how to make one cell span several rows.
Is this possible with `matrix`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a bit of cheating here, but I couldn't think a better solution.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,font=\small,
    every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,rectangle, minimum height=2.5em, text centered},
    comp/.style={draw,very thick,text width=2.5cm,fill=blue!10},
    crit/.style={draw,text width=2cm}, anchor=east]
\matrix (m) [ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=1.5mm, row sep=3mm]
{
\node (A) [comp] {Category\\One}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\One}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Two}; \&
\\
\node [comp] {Category\\Two}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Three}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Four};
\\
\node (C) [comp] {Category\\Three}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Five}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Six}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Seven};
\\
\node (D) [comp,text width=4cm] {Category\\Four}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Eight}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Nine}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Ten}; \&
\\
};

\draw[comp] (D.west |- A.north) coordinate (aux1) rectangle ($(C.south west) - (3mm,0mm)$) coordinate (aux2) {};
\node[anchor=center, rotate=90] (X) at ($(aux1)!.5!(aux2)$) {Master one};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

### Update

Ignasi noticed in a comment that the rectangle at the left does not perfectly align with the other cells, and suggests a workaround. Unfortunately, the workaround does not work, because coordinates `aux1` and `aux2` are calculated by tikz at the border of the lines of the cells, so taking into account the line width, and `fitting` library will use those coordinates as corners of the new node, at the middle of the border line. I.e. we will get the same result than in above code.

However, if we specify a negative `inner sep` for the `fit`ted node to counteract the line width, we can achieve perfect alignment.

In addition, providing a `text width` to the rotated node allows the insertion of "line breaks" (`\\`) as requested by the OP.

This is the new code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,font=\small,
    every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,rectangle, minimum height=2.5em, text centered},
    comp/.style={draw,very thick,text width=2.5cm,fill=blue!10},
    crit/.style={draw,text width=2cm}, anchor=east]
\matrix (m) [ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=1.5mm, row sep=3mm]
{
\node (A) [comp] {Category\\One}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\One}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Two}; \&
\\
\node [comp] {Category\\Two}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Three}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Four};
\\
\node (C) [comp] {Category\\Three}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Five}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Six}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Seven};
\\
\node (D) [comp,text width=4cm] {Category\\Four}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Eight}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Nine}; \&
\node [crit] {Attribute\\Ten}; \&
\\
};

\coordinate (aux1) at (D.west |- A.north);
\coordinate (aux2) at ($(C.south west) - (3mm,0mm)$);
\node[comp, fit=(aux1)(aux2), inner sep=-.6pt] (X) {}; 
\node[text width=3cm, text centered, anchor=center, rotate=90] at (X.center) {Master\\one};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the new result:

[image: New result]

Comment: I'd suggest using a `\node` fitting `aux1` and `aux2` instead of `drawing` a `rectangle`. Nodes have anchors in their external border, while rectangles in the middle of the line. If you look carefully, your solutions has `master one` left and top borders not aligned with `Category four` left and `Category one` top borders.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, JLDiaz. However, if you wouldn't mind, I'd like to leave this question open for a while. The alignment of the nodes doesn't look quite "right", as lgnasi already pointed out including an explanation.

Comment: Actually, it works perfectly fine and the offset is barely noticable when printed out. Thanks again!

Comment: @dhst I've updated the answer