# TikZ multi-row matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to adapt the solution proposed by [@JLDiaz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12571/jldiaz) to [Spanning a cell across several rows in TikZ-matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167483/spanning-a-cell-across-several-rows-in-tikz-matrix) in order to have multiple multi-rows within a TikZ `matrix`.

This is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,fit}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\csep}
\setlength{\csep}{1.5mm}

\newlength{\twidth}
\setlength{\twidth}{25mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,font=\small,
    every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,rectangle, minimum height=2.5em, text centered},
    comp/.style={draw,very thick,text width=\twidth,fill=blue!10}]
\matrix (m) [ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=\csep, row sep=3mm]
{
\node (l5) [comp] {5}; \& \\
\node (l4) [comp] {4}; \& \\
\node (l3) [comp] {3}; \& \node[comp]{3'};\\
\node (l2) [comp] {2};\\
\node (l1) [comp] {1};\\
};
\coordinate (aux5) at  ($(l5.north east) + (\csep,0)$);
\coordinate (aux4) at ($(l4.south east) + (\csep+\twidth,0)$);
\node[comp, fit=(aux4)(aux5), inner sep=-.6pt] (X45) {}; 
\node[text width=3cm, text centered, anchor=center] at (X45.center) {4' 5'};

\coordinate (aux2) at  ($(l2.north east) + (\csep,0)$);
\coordinate (aux1) at ($(l1.south east) + (\csep+\twidth,0)$);
\node[comp, fit=(aux1)(aux2),  inner sep=-.6pt]
(X12) {}; 
\node[text width=3cm, text centered, anchor=center] at (X12.center) {1' 2'};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the boxes "4' 5'" and "3'" do not have equal width:

[image]

How can I make all boxes in the second column have the same width?

And: Is there an easier solution to get some boxes spanning multiple rows than to create those `aux` coordinates?

Comment: if you drop `draw` from `comp` style, it works ok. This is because you don't take the line width into account when you calculate `aux`. You can correct this by putting `\csep+\twidth+3*\pgflinewidth` in place of `\csep+\twidth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those boxes are not equally wide because of the negative `inner sep` values. Make them zero. Also in the definition of `aux` coordinates you have to add `1.5\pgflinewidth` like:

```
\coordinate (aux5) at  ($(l5.north east) + (\csep+1.5\pgflinewidth,-1.5\pgflinewidth)$);
\coordinate (aux4) at ($(l4.south east) + (\csep+\twidth+1.5\pgflinewidth,1.5\pgflinewidth)$);
\node[comp, fit=(aux4)(aux5), inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (X45) {};
\node[text width=3cm, text centered, anchor=center] at (X45.center) {4' 5'};
```

The full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,fit}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\csep}
\setlength{\csep}{1.5mm}

\newlength{\twidth}
\setlength{\twidth}{25mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,font=\small,
    every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,rectangle, minimum height=2.5em, text centered},
    comp/.style={draw,very thick,text width=\twidth,fill=blue!10}]
\matrix (m) [ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=\csep, row sep=3mm]
{
\node (l5) [comp] {5}; \& \\
\node (l4) [comp] {4}; \& \\
\node (l3) [comp] {3}; \& \node[comp]{3'};\\
\node (l2) [comp] {2};\\
\node (l1) [comp] {1};\\
};
\coordinate (aux5) at  ($(l5.north east) + (\csep+1.5\pgflinewidth,-1.5\pgflinewidth)$);
\coordinate (aux4) at ($(l4.south east) + (\csep+\twidth+1.5\pgflinewidth,1.5\pgflinewidth)$);
\node[comp, fit=(aux4)(aux5), inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (X45) {};
\node[text width=3cm, text centered, anchor=center] at (X45.center) {4' 5'};

\coordinate (aux2) at  ($(l2.north east) + (\csep+1.5\pgflinewidth,-1.5\pgflinewidth)$);
\coordinate (aux1) at ($(l1.south east) + (\csep+\twidth+1.5\pgflinewidth,1.5\pgflinewidth)$);
\node[comp, fit=(aux1)(aux2),  inner sep=0pt]
(X12) {};
\node[text width=3cm, text centered, anchor=center] at (X12.center) {1' 2'};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like box "5" and box "4' 5'" are not aligned at the top, and box "4" and box "4' 5'" are not aligned at the bottom; how can that be solved?

Comment: @m.s. My fault. Now they are aligned. I forgot to do adjustments in y coordinate earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what is behind of decision to use `matrix` as base for desired image. It can be relative simple (to my opinion more than with use of matrix) to draw with out use of matrix:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains}

    \begin{document}
\newlength{\twidth}
\setlength{\twidth}{25mm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5mm,
      start chain = going above,       
every node/.style = {rectangle, draw, ultra thick, fill=blue!10,
                     text width=\twidth, minimum height=2.5em, 
                     inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm,
                     text centered, font=\small,
                     on chain},
                        ]
% first column
\node (l1) {1};\\
\node (l2) {2};\\
\node (l3) {3};\\
\node (l4) {4};\\
\node (l5) {5};\\
% second column
\path   let \p1 = (l1.south),
            \p2 = (l2.north),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in
        node[above right =0mm and 3mm of l1.south east,
             minimum height=\n1] {1' 2'}
        node {3'}
        node[minimum height=\n1] {4' 5'};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, node are put chains. Heights of taller nodes in second column is calculated with distance between first two lover nodes in the first column.  Until the nodes in the first column has equal heights, this simplification doesn't make troubles.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Following code shows an alternative to Harish Kumar solution. It also uses `fit` library and draws multirow nodes after `matrix` but shows how to do it without `calc` library and a second node for node's text.

```
\node[comp, fit={(l2.north-|l32.west) (l1.south-|l32.east)},  
      inner sep=0pt, label=center:{1' 2'}] (X12) {};
```

defines a fitting node with two corners declared with `perpendicular` coordinates system. `Label` with `center` option is used to place node's contents.

In order to make `fit` node with equal size as second column node, `outer sep=0pt` must be added to `comp` style.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\csep}
\setlength{\csep}{1.5mm}

\newlength{\twidth}
\setlength{\twidth}{25mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,font=\small,
    every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,rectangle, minimum height=2.5em, text centered},
    comp/.style={draw,very thick,text width=\twidth,fill=blue!10,outer sep=0pt}]
\matrix (m) [ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=\csep, row sep=3mm]
{
\node (l5) [comp] {5}; \& \\
\node (l4) [comp] {4}; \& \\
\node (l3) [comp] {3}; \& \node (l32) [comp]{3'};\\
\node (l2) [comp] {2};\\
\node (l1) [comp] {1};\\
};
\node[comp, fit={(l5.north-|l32.west) (l4.south-|l32.east)}, 
       inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, label=center:{4' 5'}] (X45) {};

\node[comp, fit={(l2.north-|l32.west) (l1.south-|l32.east)},  
       inner sep=0pt, label=center:{1' 2'}]
(X12) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]